# Flicker of ImageTextButton in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm creating a store stage in libgdx using their Scene2d.ui package. I'm seeing this really weird flicker when showing the stage where some larger versions of the buttons appear behind smaller buttons:
[image: Larger buttons appearing in background]

The larger background buttons flicker on and off, while the front ones appear completely normal. The background ones aren't clickable, but the front ones are - again, they appear completely normal.

Here is the relevant code:

```
private void init(Skin skin) {
   this.skin = skin;

   boyTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/character.png"));
   catTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/character_cat_girl.png"));
   hornTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/character_horn_girl.png"));
   pinkTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/character_pink_girl.png"));
   queenTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/character_queen_girl.png"));

   // set root table
   table = new Table();
   table.setFillParent(true);
   addActor(table);

   table.add(new Label("Characters: ", skin, "default")).padLeft(10).colspan(2);
   table.row();
   ButtonGroup characterGroup = new ButtonGroup();
   characterGroup.setMaxCheckCount(1);
   Button boyButton = createImageTextButton("Plain Boy", boyTexture);
   table.add(boyButton);
   Button catButton = createImageTextButton("Cat Girl", catTexture);
   table.add(catButton);
   table.row();
   Button hornButton = createImageTextButton("Horn Girl", hornTexture);
   table.add(hornButton);
   Button pinkButton = createImageTextButton("Pink Girl", pinkTexture);
   table.add(pinkButton);
   table.row();
   Button queenButton = createImageTextButton("Queen", queenTexture);
   table.add(queenButton).colspan(2);

   //addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.alpha(1f), Actions.fadeIn(1)));
}

private Button createImageTextButton(String label, Texture texture) {
   ImageTextButton button = new ImageTextButton(label, skin, "default");
   button.getImage().setDrawable(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(texture)));
   return button;
}
```

At first I thought it had something to do with the transition actions, but as you can see I've commented them out and it's still happening.

I also thought that it was a problem with just ImageTextButton, but I changed my `createImageTextButton` method to return a plain `TextButton`. That still has a flicker but the buttons aren't enlarged in the background - they seem to flicker on the sides but are roughly the same size as the foreground ones.

Here are the constructors, as requested in comments below:

```
public Store(Skin skin) {
    super();
    init(skin);
}

public Store(Viewport viewport, Skin skin) {
    super(viewport);
    init(skin);
}

public Store(Viewport viewport, Batch batch, Skin skin) {
    super(viewport, batch);
    init(skin);
}
```

I'm using the last one when creating the stage in my MainGame class.

```
public class MainGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    public static final int MIN_WIDTH = 480;
    public static final int MIN_HEIGHT = 800;

    public static SpriteBatch batch;
    public static GameStage game;
    public static Store store;
    public static Skin skin;
    public static Viewport viewport;
    public static Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        viewport = new ExtendViewport(MIN_WIDTH, MIN_HEIGHT);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        initSkin();
        game = new GameStage(viewport, batch, skin);
        store = new Store(viewport, batch, skin);
        setStage(game);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void render() {
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height, true);
    }

    ...

    public static void setStage(Stage stage) {
        MainGame.stage = stage;
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `render()` method? Where/When do you call the `init()` method?

Comment: I'm not overriding the render() method so it's just the default Stage.render() method. The init method is called within the constructors. I'll add the constructors above.

Comment: In the `render()` you call `stage.draw()`, where `stage` should be the `game` right? Where do you call `store.stage.draw()`?

Comment: Store extends Stage so I swap out the `stage` variable in the MainGame. The render method just calls `draw` on whatever the current stage is.

Comment: It's hard to say whats wrong, the shown code seems okay, i guess the problem is somewhere else... Did you try to debug your code? Set a breakpoint inside your `render()` and look what `Stage`, `Viewport` etc. is.

Comment: I did, I see that the stage is correct - meaning I can confirm the variable is being swapped out properly. I did debug the viewport, but I'm not sure what to look for - the width, height, etc.. values don't change.

Comment: I eventually gave up and changed the `Store` to extend `Group` and I now set it's visibility in the `GameStage` class. I don't seem to have the flicker issue and it means I can overlay the Store if I want, so it may be a better way to go in the long run, but still would be nice to know what I'm doing wrong in case I have another situation where swapping out `Stage`s is the better solution.

Comment: I guess extending an `Actor` class and adding it to a `Stage` is a better solution then extending `Stage`. It would really be nice to know where the bug here lies, the bigger background `Button`s seems like the `Camera` or the `Viewport` change right before it draws the `Stage` another time... But if you say the `Viewport` value does not change... Strange...